# How to display database values in .cshtml corresponding to values in .cshtml.cs (razor pages)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, passwords, razor-pages

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

I am making a password generator which will generate passphrases from the [diceware wordlist](https://www.eff.org/files/2016/07/18/eff_large_wordlist.txt) and am using Razor pages

So I have a database with the diceware list, this list goes from 11111 to 66666, you can read more about diceware and how to use it [here](https://diceware.dmuth.org/).

[image to the wordlist in db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txOZ6.png)

Depending on the number of words the user requires (eg. 5 word passphrase), I'll generate that many (eg. 5) 5-digit numbers and store it in an array, I perform this in the cshtml.cs page using c#

My model page:

```cs
//testdiceware.cs
public class testdiceware
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; } 
    public string word { get; set; }
}
```

The ApplicationDbContext:

```cs
//ApplicationDbContext.cs
public class ApplicationDbContext:DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<testdiceware> testdiceware { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
//PassphraseGen.cshtml.cs

//dbcontext
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
public PassphraseGenModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    _db = db;
}
public IEnumerable<testdiceware> passphrase { get; set; }

//this is to generate the 5-digit numbers
public static int[] genWord(int num)
{
    int[] dicerolls = new int[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[num * 8];
        RandomNumberGenerator.Create().GetBytes(bytes);
        UInt32 value = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 0);
        int min = 11111;
        int max = 66666;
        dicerolls[i] = (int)Math.Round(min + (max - min) * (value / (uint.MaxValue + 1.0)), 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

    }
    return dicerolls;
}
```

The problem I'm facing:

I now need to display the words corresponding to the 5-digit numbers I generated in the page-behind (.cshtml.cs) in the .cshtml (view) page, how do I go about it?

P.S.

1. This is a college project of mine, I won't actually be using this, so no need to mention that "I shouldn't be generating passwords myself"
2. The "id" is not continuous, like after 11116 there's 11121, I will have to solve that but right now I need a way to print the corresponding word to the .cshtml page

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways but most common would be to have OnGet and OnPost methods that handle when the page is requested and when the user submits the page. The Microsoft [tutorial on Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) is very good and includes examples of reading and updating a database from a razor page.

Sample code for your page model

```
public string Word { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
}

public void OnPost(int numWords)
{
    int key = genWord(numWords);
    // Lookup word in database based on key
    // Set word to Property and display on cshtml page 
}
```

Comment: If this is the database I'm working with: https://i.stack.imgur.com/txOZ6.png
if suppose I know the value 11115 which I calculated in the .cshtml.cs part, but now I want to just display the word corresponding to the id 11115 in the .cshtml, I can't understand how to do that

Comment: I added some more info to the answer but this is really to large of a question to answer as is. Try going through the tutorial and creating a more narrow question

Comment: hey thanks for spending time on my question, I'll be more precise while posting new questions, my first question after all :)

btw should I delete the question as it's vague?

Comment: @somerazorguy no worries and welcome to stackoverflow. Here's a good reference on asking a question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask